# LIKE COUNT 1 but dont count in the db

Tags: mysql

I was told to try and make a new post and explain better.

I have a upload function on my webpage. And i want to block certain titles from a database called filter. But it dont work.

The php side looks like this.

```
$DB->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter WHERE '". $Properties['Title'] ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')");
if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '<b>you cant upload this!</b>';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();
```

`$Properties['Title']` contains this in my test: The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi

The.White.Tiger. is blocked in the database filter. and if run this query in SQL

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter WHERE '". The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')`

I get count **1**

So the php side SHOULD deny upload because it has 1 entry on it.. But it dosnt? Is something wrong with the code?

I have now tried these in php witch gave 500 Internal Server error

```
SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')

if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '<b>You cant upload!</b>';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();
}
}


SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')

if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '<b>You cant upload!</b>';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();
}
}

SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')

if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
    $Err = '<b>You cant upload!</b>';
    include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
    die();
}
}
```

All off the above gave 500 internal server error

Comment: After `WHERE` comes name of a table field, not value.

Comment: Consider to share your table structure with us.

Comment: Oouupp i typed wrong... 
It DOS block The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi from upload but it also blockes
The.White.Dog.test.soen.avi

But if i run 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM filter WHERE '". The.White.Dog.test.soen.avi ."' LIKE CONCAT('%', filter, '%')

I get a count of 0 in pma query

Comment: Tabel stuckture
  id  int(11)    Nej  None  AUTO_INCREMENT 
 2  filter  varchar(255)  latin1_swedish_ci

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from a query you want to find existsing records with title like user (or someone else) entered.
Here you have two errors:

1. Wrong `WHERE` clause. After `WHERE` comes name of a table field, not value
2. `filter` in CONCAT is what? What's it value?

Suppose title column name in your table `filter` is `column_title`.
And you are looking for already existing title **The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi** in a table `filter`.
The query should be like this:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'column_title' LIKE CONCAT('%', 'The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi', '%')`

After query you have to check value of `count` and compare it to 1. If it's equals or more than 1 - you already have this title. Else - title is not in the table and you can perform adding or something else.

**UPDATE**:

As I see your real table structure - you should replace `column_title` to `filter`:

`SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', 'The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi', '%')`

Comment: If i understand you correctly the query in the php should be like this

     SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '$Properties['Title']', '%')

  if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
        $Err = '<b>You cant upload this!</b>';
        include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
        die();

Comment: You are right. But in case if you are selecting `COUNT(*)` mysql-query result will always have one row. The value of `count` will be stored in this row. So, I suppose `record_count` will always return **1** for any query. So you have to use another method and get exactly the value of a `count`.

Comment: How would you make the db query so that it would only deny upload if it found a match in filter column?

Comment: As I already said either using my original query `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', 'The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi', '%')` - but here you have to get value of a `count`. Or like this: `SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', 'The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi', '%')` - here you will be get exactly rows of data. And `record_count` will return count of rows.

Comment: Something was also wrong. I got server error on that mysql
 SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '$Properties['Title']', '%')
Am i forgetting something the &Proberties['Title'] ?

Comment: SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '$Properties['Title']', '%')

Also gave server error in the php

Comment: `count` is a reserved word in Mysql, so it would be better to backtick it.

Comment: ('%', '$Properties['Title']', '%')

im thinking there is something wrong there, because if i just to the titel in manuelly it works, but not like that

Comment: Stil server error on :  SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '$Properties['Title']', '%')

Comment: maybe concatenating helps& like in your question `"CONCAT('%', '" . $value . "', '%')"`

Comment: Use not ' but ` for ``count``.

Comment: Im getting confused now.. Im trying with the one you say with ID, and trying this 2 gives me server error:
SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE "CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')"

and tried this one to :

SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')
Both gives me server error.

Comment: Its now like this
    SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')
 
    if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
        $Err = '<b>You cant upload this!</b>';
        include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
        die();
    }
}

Comment: 500
Internal Server Error

Comment: Can you edit your question and show what php+mysql variants you have tried?

Comment: And where is `$DB->query(`?

Comment: Just testet :
     $DB->query(SELECT id FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')
 
    if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
        $Err = '<b>You cant upload this!</b>';
        include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
        die();
    }
}
And it gave 500 internal

Comment: Thx now the the internal error is gone, if i use select id, it dosnt block The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi or The.White.Dog.test.soen.avi. If i use COUNT(*) as count it blocks both The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi and The.White.Dog.test.soen.avi even though that only The.White.Tiger. exist in the filter database

Comment: Some problem that i had to begin with, it blocks the one that i should, but also the one that looks alittle like it

Comment: Check what value `record_count` returns. And check maybe it's `LIKE` behaviour blocks all records.

Comment: Even though this query give 0 results in pma
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . The.White.Dog.test.soen.avi . "', '%')

Comment: Im new at mysql, how do i check what record_count returns?

Comment: Can i return that in the $Err msg?

Comment: In pma i tried this one because you said that is better to use id
SELECT id
FROM filter
WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT( '%', '" . The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi . "', '%' )

It return nothing, but The.White.Tiger. exist in the filter database so that why the script didnt block on that one, should the query be changed to work with ID?

Comment: $DB->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM filter WHERE 'filter' LIKE CONCAT('%', '" . $Properties['Title'] . "', '%')");
 
    if($DB->record_count() != 0) {
        $Err = '<b>You cant upload this!</b>';
        include(SERVER_ROOT . '/sections/upload/upload.php');
        die();
    }
This query we have not actully blocks EVERYTHING from being upload

Comment: I found a error. SELECT id FROM filter WHERE filter LIKE CONCAT('%', 'The.White.Tiger.Test.Dawe.avi', '%')
Dos not return anything i PMA
but
SELECT id FROM filter WHERE filter LIKE CONCAT('%', 'The.White.Tiger', '%') dos...

Isnt it possible to make it so dosnt need a exact MATCH, but as long as The.White.Tiger is part off the title

Comment: SELECT filter
FROM filter
WHERE filter LIKE CONCAT( '%', 'The.White.Tige', '%' )
LIMIT 0 , 30
Also returns 1 result but not the one i was looking for. Im goiing to make a new post about that error